# What is the general solution of $\tan^2x- \sqrt3 \tan x -\tan x= -\sqrt3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I require some help finding the answer to the above equation. I have tried using the quadratic formula, however I couldn't get the answer $-\sqrt3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: The quadratic formula is one way to do it.  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you want to use the quadratic formula, you should first rewrite it:$ \tan^2x- \sqrt3 \tan x -\tan x+\sqrt3=0$, then use $a=\tan^2x, b=-\sqrt3-1, c=\sqrt3$

Comment: $tan (x)=\sqrt 3$ satisfies the equation, S0 $x=2k\pi + \frac {\pi}3$.Also $x=2k\pi+\frac {\pi}4$ is another solution.

Comment: Hi, do you mean $\sqrt3$ is a solution (ie without the $\mathbf{-}$ sign)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have
$$
\tan^2 x - \sqrt{3}\tan x - \tan x = -\sqrt{3},
$$
this is
$$
\tan^2 x - \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)\tan x + \sqrt{3} = 0.
$$
Substituting $\tan x=y$, you get
$$
y^2 - \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)y + \sqrt{3} = 0
$$
We get the following values for $y$:
$$
\begin{split}
y=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1\pm\sqrt{\left(-\sqrt{3}-1\right)^2-4\sqrt{3}}}{2} & = %
\frac{\sqrt{3}+1\pm\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}}{2}=\\[1em]
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}+1\pm\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)}{2}=
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\sqrt{3}\\1\end{array}\right.
\end{split}
$$
So either $\tan x=\sqrt{3}$ or $\tan x=1$.

In the first case
$$
x=\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}\quad\vee\quad x=\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)+\pi=\frac{4}{3}\pi.
$$
In the second case instead
$$
x=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}\quad\vee\quad x=\arctan(1)+\pi=\frac{5}{4}\pi.
$$
It follows that the set of solutions is
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi\quad\vee\quad x=\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi,
$$
for all $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the quadratic formula, but alternatively we can use the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) to check if $\tan x=\sqrt 3$ is a solution to
$$\tan^2x-\sqrt 3 \tan x-\tan x+\sqrt 3=0$$
simply by substituting in $\tan x=\sqrt 3$ and checking if the output is indeed $0$.

Alternatively, we can note the following:
$$\begin{align}\tan^2x-\sqrt 3 \tan x-\tan x+\sqrt 3&=\tan^2x-(\sqrt3+1)\tan x +(-1)(-\sqrt3)\\
&=(\tan x-\sqrt 3)(\tan x -1)\end{align}$$
which now enables us to easily solve our equation.

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.